# How to turn off external hard-drive when hibernating PC?

Tags: external-hdd, hibernate

I sometimes connect external hard-drives (with their own power supply and without) via USB. They are constantly spinning, which doesn't bother me that much since I usually use them when they are connected.

However, it happened multiple times that I take a break and put the PC in hibernation mode, and when I come back the PC is "off" (in hibernation or sleep) but the external drives are still on and spinning.

Is there a way to fix this? Do I need to turn off USB power for hibernation in general or is there a specific setting for hard-drives?

PS: Ideally, the drive would also stop spinning when the PC is on but the drive is not used.

*This is on Manjaro Gnome*

Comment: I don't have hibernation configured on my system so I can't try out stuff for you. You should have a look at the [`hdparm`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hdparm) ArchWiki page and to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/137585) on Ubuntu.SX.

Comment: I tried it with hdparm, that did not work, but I was able to set spin down time with sdparm. The problem is, that even if the drive is not spinning anymore while the PC is on, it starts as soon the PC is in hibernation. So the PC shuts down and turns off the vents, and the drive starts spinning